# What are the visa requirements of Malaysia for French citizens in 2015?

Tags: visas, malaysia, french-citizens

Must I have a Visa at all?

I yes, can I get a Visa on arrival (at the airport if arriving by plane, or at the border if arriving by bus/train) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a French citizen, one does **not** need a visa to stay in Malaysia up to 3 months (90 days I suppose, the exact number of days is not specified on the website for some reason).

See the [website of the Malaysian embassy in Paris](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/fra_paris/requirement_foreigner) for further details.

See also the [Wikipedia list of Visa requirements per country for French citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_French_citizens) - although you should always triple check what is mentioned here with what official authorities say.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that if it says 3 months it is 90 days (it will say so on the visa stamp)